# Is there a NN-Model which has multiple outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

## This is what I am trying to accomplish:

Predict **Y** based on **X**,that is `Y ~ X`:

1.**`X = {n, x_1, x_2, x_3, ...}`**

- a vector of factors
- size unchanged: `X.size() = DIM_X`

2.**Y = {}**

- also a vector
- size changing according to `n` in **X**: `Y.size() = 4 * n`

## So, can I do this with NNs ? is there a NN-Model I can refer to ? Or Is there other approaches can solve this ？

**Edit:**

Sample data:

```
1 0.1 109 123.7 0 0 512 512
2 0.8 201 88.7 384 216 384 246 0 0 1024 768
```

In the above, first 4 elements each row represents **X**, what's left is **Y**.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Ignore my first comment (if you saw it). Your question is not very clear though. Perhaps add a few simplified data examples. Probably a RNN model can do what you want.

Comment: I agree with some examples and some more info about n, is n bounded and if so what is the cardinality?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, see my edits above, is it more clear?

Comment: My original dataset is far more complicated though.

Comment: Some info about n? If that is always 10 or less is a very different problem than if it can grow up to 2000

Comment: n can be 1 to 20.

Comment: In your sample data, are the first four features of Y representing the same things for n = 1 and n = 2?  (I.e., are they coming from the same probability distribution?)

Comment: Yes, they are, actually the first four represent the `OpenGL Window(LeftBottom.x, LeftBottom.y, width, height)`, also the next four. `n` in **X** meaning how many sub windows I have, while **Y** represent the every `OpenGL sub window`.